# Story generation

Tags: language-agnostic

Upon reading a [blog post about a minimalist story-generating python program](http://grandtextauto.org/2008/11/20/story-generation-in-1k/), I was asking myself - and you - which are the most successful attempts at such programs. I remember seeing something using generating grammars, for instance. And which are the best attempts that, like this one, are extremely compact, either self-contained or able to read, say, the Web or an independent textual corpus (but not simply a file with a large number of story chunks)?

Comment: This is not an "opinion based" answer or question. Artificial Intelligence for Story Generation and Simulation is a very fascinating AI field that has been around since the 70s. The question asks for algorithms and coding techniques to allow an AI Agent to generate a story that are used currently. This is a "fact/reference/specific example" question, and NOT opinion based.

Comment: I am the OP. First of all, I am puzzled by the fact that my question raises concern almost *six* years after having been asked. And, as to the concerns themselves, I asked about a specific kind of programs and algorithms, not about opinions or preferences; and this kind of programs is so restricted that it is not as if I asked about, say, databases.

Comment: If someone may suggest a way to rephrase a request for information about story-generating algorithms, I'll be glad to comply.

Answer (score 4):

Search for Talespin for some famous ground breaking work. (Example: [Micro-Talespin in Common Lisp](http://norvig.com/ltd/test/micro-tale-spin.lisp) by Warren Sack.)

Comment: You're much more likely to get upvotes if you give some direct links as opposed to a generic "search for."

Comment: http://norvig.com/ltd/test/micro-tale-spin.lisp

Answer (score 3):

I actually like Turner's "Minstrel: A Computer Model of Creativity and Storytelling" better :
ftp://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/tech-report/1992-reports/920057.pdf

Talespin is, in my opinion, blind in it's algorithm to everything but planning. So the author goals are given very little consideration (if at all). Minstrel is better that way.